# Why do I get an error with lookup in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've written the code below with lookup in Haskell:

```
justCheck ::  a -> b -> Environment -> Bool
justCheck x y env = case lookup x env of
                                    Just a -> find y env
                                    Nothing -> error "Variable not found."
```

When I try to run the code, I get an error on 'Normal' and 'Just' on these lines:

```
          Just a -> find y env
          Nothing -> error "Variable not found."
```

The method find searches through the list Environment to see if y exists in it, and I don't get any errors on it.

The datatype Environment is defined as [(String,Int)]

Could anyone explain why I get an error on these lines?

Edit:

find is defined as:

```
find :: Int -> [(String, Int)] -> Bool
find y [] = error "Variable not found"
find y (x:xs) = if y == (snd x) then True else find y xs
```

Comment: `find` does not return a `Bool`. Since the signature of your function is supposed to return a `Bool`, there is thus a mismatch between the return type of `find`, and the return type of `justCheck x y env`

Comment: Your type is too general; you can't use values of arbitrary types `a` with `lookup` if `env :: [(String, Int)]`; `x` must be a `String`.

Comment: Drop the type annotation, and you'll see the inferred type for `justCheck` is `Eq a => a -> ((a, b) -> Bool) -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe (a, b)`. Taking into consideration the known type of `Environment`, this becomes `String -> ((String, Int) -> Bool) -> Environment -> Maybe (String, Int)`.

Comment: Ok, so you aren't using `Data.List.find`. The type of `justCheck` is still too general; you are claiming that `x` and `y` can be any type whatsoever, but `lookup` will expect `x` to be a `String` and `find will expect `y` to be an `Int`.

Comment: And why are you using `error` instead of returning `False`?

Comment: I want to return a message when the program finds that the input is wrong. That's why i return an error instead of False.

Comment: Why don't you do like `justCheck x y = any (\e -> (fst e == x) && (snd  e == y)` where `type Env a b = [(a,b)]` and `justCheck :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> Env a b -> Bool`.. ?

Comment: You aren't "returning" an error; you're crashing your program. `"Variable not found."` doesn't really convey any more information than `False` would; if there's only one possible non-true result, it may as well be `False` rather than an arbitrary string.

Comment: You could use a return type like `Either String ()` or `Maybe String` (with `Nothing` standing for success) if you really want an error message in place of a failure value, though a new type isomorphic to them would probably read better. For example, `data LookupResult = Found | NotFound String`.